Is there a built-in command in nestjs to generate a repository?
I tried the command
$ nest g repository users

But it didn't work, I wonder, was there any previous version of Nestjs that used this command and now it no longer exists?

The repository was never available in the @nestjs/schematics. So that command was never possible assuming that you're using the default collection
